# Can you undo this community Wiki Answer by me?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

Sorry, I posted this [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/54559/er-epr-and-information-fuelling-cosmic-expansion), Can you please revert this via Moderator Assistance?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- I've gone and done it. In the future, feel free to just flag the post, though; it makes documenting our actions a little easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me!